# Jquery .get not working in Firefox and IE

Tags: api, internet-explorer, jquery, firefox

I'm using the awesome [GoSquared API](https://www.gosquared.com/developer/) to get the number of current visitors on my Site.

I have build a Jquery Script, that automatically updates the number every two seconds with Jquery `.get`, but this doesn't seem to work in IE and Firefox.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Asustaba/JU3Yy/2/)**

Thanks :)

Comment: @zod Works fine in Chrome, Opera and Safari

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Firefox `data` is a string for some reason. You can specify the data type of the response explicitly:

```
$.get('url', function(){}, "json");
```

Otherwise you can turn it into an object like this:

```
if (typeof data === "string"){
    data = JSON.parse(data);
}
```